# Using PHP to create a stream -

Tags: php, stream, media

I would like to use PHP to read from a file and stream it out.

My code looks something like this:

teststream.php

```
$bufsize=4096; // amount of buffer to read at a time.

$h = fopen("test.wav", "rb");
$stdout = fopen("php://stdout", "wb");

while ( !feof($h) ) {
    $buf = fread($h, $bufsize);
    fwrite($stdout, $buf);
}

pclose( $h );
```

And then I would like to be able to put that into a media player (like VLC for example) as:

```
http://www.test.com/teststream.php
```

This approach is not working, and I'm not sure why.

---- updated code now looks like this:

```
<?php

$bufsize=4096; // amount of buffer to read at a time.

$h = fopen(dirname(__FILE__)."/test.wav", "rb");
header("Content-Type: audio/x-wav", true);
$stdout = fopen("php://stdout", "wb");

$total=0;
while ( !feof($h) ) {
    $buf = fread($h, $bufsize);

    $total=$total+strlen($buf);
    error_log("buf read: ".strlen($buf).", total: ".$total);

    fwrite($stdout, $buf);
}

fclose( $h );
```

And the Apache error_log looks like this:

```
[Wed Oct 30 00:29:12 2013] [error] [client 50.201.227.222] buf read: 4096, total: 4096
[Wed Oct 30 00:29:12 2013] [error] [client 50.201.227.222] buf read: 4096, total: 8192
[Wed Oct 30 00:29:12 2013] [error] [client 50.201.227.222] buf read: 4096, total: 12288
...
...
```

So it looks like it's sending out the data, but it never plays the audio on the VLC side.  If I point VLC to http://www.test.com/test.wav then it plays just fine...  ??

Comment: You probably need to send out a [header](http://www.php.net/header) with the content type which I'm assuming is a video type. Also, `pclose` is used when  you `popen`. You probably want `fclose`.

Comment: I did add -- header("Content-type: audio/wav"); but it didn't seem to make a difference.  Also - yeah, I'm actually trying to do something different, but yeah, you're right about pclose.

Comment: as Steyx said, are there any errors? If you remove the header, are you seeing any output? Without the header, you should should see the raw file as if you opened it in a text editor. If you don't see anything, check your error log for a fatal error.

Comment: VLC just skips past it to the next file.  I tried the changes the answer below suggests and then it just hangs - but at least it's staying on that stream...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this in one my project and it works like a charm:

```
//send file contents
$fp=fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . "/test.wav", "rb");
header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="test.wav"');
header("Content-transfer-encoding: binary");
header("Content-length: ".filesize(dirname(__FILE__) . "/test.wav")."    ");
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: so what's the difference between fpassthru and fwrite ?

Comment: Somtimes php://stdout doesnt work as expexted. Other thing is the headers you send. You can try to use mixed method and see the results.

Comment: Can I use this php stream script to use it for multiple users at the same time? @bksi

Answer (score 0):

Is PHP reporting any errors? Perhaps it can't find the test.wav. 
If this file is in the same folder as your PHP script, just change your code to the following:

```
$bufsize=4096; // amount of buffer to read at a time.

$h = fopen(dirname(__FILE__) . "/test.wav", "rb");
$stdout = fopen("php://stdout", "wb");

while ( !feof($h) ) {
    $buf = fread($h, $bufsize);
    fwrite($stdout, $buf);
}

pclose( $h );
```

Oh.. and yes add a header to your output like this:

```
header("Content-Type: audio/x-wav", true);
```